# Tinymce multiple instances in multiple languages on the same page

Tags: php, jquery, tinymce, wysiwyg, text-editor

I am trying to find the solution that how can I create multiple instances of tinymce editor (Each in different language) but tinymce is not supporting it as it change the language of all the instances in the language of last created instance.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
    selector: "#editor1",
    language: 'en',
});

tinymce.init({
    selector: "#editor2",
    language: 'ar',
});

</script>

<form method="post" action="test.php">
    <textarea id="editor1"></textarea>
    <textarea id="editor2"></textarea>
</form>
```

Comment out second tinymce.int() and you see first editor in english.

Here is the online [link](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/5bhaab/1) where you can see the problem.
http://fiddle.tinymce.com/5bhaab/1

Answer (score 0):

TinyMCE does not currently support rendering its UI in multiple languages on a single web page.  If this is a feature you would like to see added you can create a Feature Request on the TinyMCE issue tracker:

https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/issues

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution that will resolve your problem is using multiple [Inline Frames](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) (`iframe`) on your page.

```
<iframe id="inlineFrameEn"
   width="300"
   height="200"
   src="/editor-en">
</iframe>

<iframe id="inlineFrameAr"
   width="300"
   height="200"
   src="/editor-ar">
</iframe>
```

You can then embed and setup the TinyMCE editor to your needs behind each `iframe`.

Using CSS you hide the borders and make the TinyMCE editors appear as if they're embedded on the current page.